# Get data from SharePoint Online List using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint, visual-studio-2019

I'm developing a solution to get data from SharePoint Online List, but when I try to retrieve and execute the query, do a error. The error is.

**System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'**

Im using 4 textboxs (URL, User, Password, NameList) and a Datagridview.

```
Using context As ClientContext = New ClientContext(TextBox1.Text.Trim())

    context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.[Default]
    context.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(TextBoxName.Text.Trim(), TextBoxPassword.Text.Trim(), "https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/SPSite/")

    Dim webObj As Web = context.Web
    Dim listObj As List = webObj.Lists.GetByTitle(TextBoxLista.Text.Trim())
    Dim cqObj As CamlQuery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100)
    Dim collObj As ListItemCollection = listObj.GetItems(cqObj)

    context.Load(collObj)
    context.ExecuteQuery() 'Line whit error

End Using
```

Could you help me to know the reason for the error and how to solve it?

Thank you in advance.

Regards.

Comment: Could you provide more details about which line of the code throw the exception? It will help others analyze your problem.

Comment: @XingyuZhao, thank you for your answer. The line is `context.ExecuteQuery()`, send the message **System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'**. In the site I'm owner.

Comment: Try using SharePointOnlineCredentials to handle handshaking, for example: context.Credentials = New SharePointOnlineCredentials("yourlogin@yoursite.onmicrosoft.com", passWord)

Comment: @XingyuZhao ready, it worked, thanks for your support and your answers. I add the answer for other colleagues who need it. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code whit the solution.

Thank you.

```
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.Client
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Net
Public Class Form4

    Dim siteUrl As String = "https://namedomain.sharepoint.com/sites/TaskSP/"
    'namedomain is the name of the site domain, TaskSP is the name site.

    Dim context As New ClientContext(siteUrl)
    Dim web As Web

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try

            Dim userNameSP As String = TextBox1.Text
            'Textbox1.text is the mail account to access site.
            Dim password As String = TextBox2.Text
            'Textbox2.text is the password of your mail account to access site.
            Dim secureString As SecureString = New NetworkCredential("", password).SecurePassword

            Dim cred = New SharePointOnlineCredentials(userNameSP, secureString)
            Dim clientContext As New ClientContext(siteUrl)
            clientContext.Credentials = cred
            Dim web As Web = clientContext.Web
            Dim oWebsite As Web = clientContext.Web
            Dim collList As ListCollection = oWebsite.Lists

            Dim oList As List = collList.GetByTitle("TestList")
            'TestList is the name of the list you want to query

            clientContext.Load(oList)

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

I hope this is useful if you need it.

Regards.